# Camel for Karaf 2.3.10

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf

I have to use Apache Karaf 2.3.10 in our environment.
I need to run Apache Camel on karaf.
I am not sure what is the recommended Camel version for karaf 2.3.10.

I was referring to [this](http://camel.apache.org/karaf.html) link for compatibility information.
There is no straight forward answer there. 
I want to use Camel 2.13 or above. 
I think 2.14.0 is the best bet since, Karaf 2.3.7 is sufficient for it and I have Karaf 2.3.10 in our environment.

NB:
My post on [Camel Users forum](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Camel-for-Karaf-2-3-10-td5770852.html) has not yielded any result so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Karaf 2.3.7 is compatible with Camel 2.14.0 so Karaf 2.3.10 is still compatible with Camel 2.14.0. The best choice is to use the newest Camel version because there is more bugfixes and more features than in the older one. So you should choose Camel 2.14.x (e.g. 2.14.3)